# How to save JSON file using JavaScript in Front-End? (Non-NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code

How to save this data into JSON file?

```
var objJson = {
  questionType : "singleLine",
  maxCharecters : 25,
  question : "What is the capital of India?",
  answer : "Delhi"
 }
```

Comment: Right click in side bar -> select 'New file' -> give it a name ending with the `.json` extension. But somehow I believe that's not what you are really asking.

Comment: `const fs = require('fs'); fs.writeFileSync('my.json', JSON.stringify(objJson));`

Comment: I wanna create a file during runtime @Mathyn

Comment: @AkashStarvinDsouza are you using NodeJS?

Comment: It shows this error when I use require('fs'); convertToJson.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined @NikitaMadeev

Comment: I'm not using NodeJs @NikitaMadeev

Answer (score 1):

You can use `JSON.stringify(objJson)` to turn it into a string, then save it to a file. I can't tell what you mean by Visual Studio Code, but if you are using NodeJS (like a VS Code extension) you can use the [File System Module](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_filesystem.asp) to save it.

Example:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync(
  'data.json', 
  JSON.stringify(objJson)
);
```

Comment: I'm not using NodeJS

Comment: Try here for a non-nodejs solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: It shows how to download a file, I want to save file locally

Comment: There is not really a way to do that in JavaScript, but you could save to `localStorage`?

Comment: How to save in local storage?

Comment: See the documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Note: You will still need to stringify your JSON

Comment: Local storage will save until we close the tab. How to save permanently into harddisk?

Comment: Only lost in private browsing. An alternative, especially for larger data is IndexedDB: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API